# NoClassDefFoundError in InternalAppEventsLogger

Tags: android, facebook, noclassdeffounderror, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using the facebook marketing. But its show this kind of exaptions

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

```
"com.facebook.appevents.InternalAppEventsLogger" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.sugaronly.sugaronly-NlRH5joNmKqTTw0NxLNWuw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sugaronly.sugaronly-NlRH5joNmKqTTw0NxLNWuw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
```

Gradle file:-

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:[4,5)'
```

Implement code in android side

```
    setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(true);
    AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this);
    logger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_X);
```